# OpenCVsharp4 save Image at max resolution

Tags: c#, windows, opencv, webcam

I am using Opencvsharp from shimat for building an application. Code simply opens camera, saves the image and close it using below code.

```
using OpenCvSharp;

VideoCapture capture;
Mat frame;

private void btn_Camera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    capture = new VideoCapture();          
    frame = new Mat();
    capture.Open(1);
    capture.Read(frame);

    if (capture.Read(frame))
    {
        frame.SaveImage("@test.jpg");
    }

    capture.Release();
}
```

However the picture is saved at 640x480 resolution whereas the camera is capable of capturing 1280x720 resolution pictures.
I tried setting the `VideoCapture` properties like below

```
capture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameHeight, 720);
capture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameWidth, 1280);
```

But still the saved image is of 480p resolution. Is there a way to save it at 720p resolution, like the default windows camera app does.

Also I don't want to save it in 480p and then resize to 720p as that doesn't help in getting the details that needs to captured.

I know in opencv Python its possible. Am looking for something similar in C# with Opencvsharp4

Comment: What is the camera model,  can you share ?

Comment: Logitech c270 720p webacm

Comment: Did you also try: `capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);`

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk this is for c++. What i need is in C#. For C# its capture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameHeight, 720); & capture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameWidth, 1280); , which also is not working.

Comment: You can not expect all cameras working with opencv backends properly. Every kind of camera has its own driver and opencv some supports and some not. You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902985/cant-change-opencv-video-capture-resolution/64906610#64906610)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When capturing via OpenCvSharp, 640x480 is the default resolution.

You must set the desired resolution *before* the device is opened (which is done implicitly when you grab frames) e.g.:

```
    int frameWidth = 1280;
    int frameHeight = 720;
    int cameraDeviceId = 1;
    var videoCapture = VideoCapture.FromCamera(cameraDeviceId);
    if (!videoCapture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameWidth, frameWidth))
    {
        logger.LogWarning($"Failed to set FrameWidth to {frameWidth}");
    }
    if (!videoCapture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameHeight, frameHeight))
    {
        logger.LogWarning($"Failed to set FrameHeight to {frameHeight}");
    }
    using (videoCapture)
    {
        videoCapture.Grab();
        var image = videoCapture.RetrieveMat();
        logger.LogInformation($"Image size [{image.Width} x {image.Height}]");
    }
```

Comment: Will try it out and confirm. Although i have used something similar in my questing above. the resolution while logging it, is coming as updated, but saveimage just saves it in 640x480 only.

Comment: Maybe try saving to a new file. When I use `image.SaveImage` to save. the file resolution is consistent with the Width and Height properties.